# VS15 C++ Redistributable unknown error code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, psexec, error-code, redistributable

I'm trying to install VS15 C++ Redistributable on remote machine using PsExec.

> command='C:\temp\vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet'

The installation finishes with

> Return code= 23

I've checked manually that Redistributable package is installed on the machine after this procedure.

I can't find any information about error code = 23. What can cause this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I've found that this error code meant that KB2999266 update (included in redistributable package) could not be installed. However the rest of redistributable package installed successfully.